# Difficulty Comparing Two Arrays In Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I can't seem to compare these two arrays on Kotlin.

```
var temp = ingredientsList.toArray()
var temp2 = chickenTikkaMasala.get(0).ingredients
if(ingredientsList.toArray().contentEquals(chickenTikkaMasala.get(0).ingredients)) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Chicken Tikka Worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

[image: Temp and Temp2 debug screenshot]

[image: Screenshot of Code]

Answer (score 2):

The `contentEquals` function will only return true if the arrays contain the same elements in the same order. Your arrays doesn't have the same order.
From the docs:

```
/**
 * Returns `true` if the two specified arrays are *structurally* equal to one another,
 * i.e. contain the same number of the same elements in the same order.
 *
```

Comment: Is there a way of non-structurally comparing the two arrays?

Comment: Did you not see the other answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested whether an item exists in the collection, then you really deal with sets here, not lists or arrays. So you need to compare them as sets:

```kotlin
ingredientsList.toSet() == chickenTikkaMasala.get(0).ingredients.toSet()
```